# Is there a way to parse numbers from a html input without parseInt one at a time

Tags: javascript

I was wondering if there was a better way to write this in Javascript?
E.g if I got two numbers from my html form, instead of parseInt them one by one, is there a better way in which i can make the code more efficient say there were 20 numbers i receive from my input.

Thanks in advance

```
let itemOne = req.body.ItemOne
    let itemTwo = req.body.ItemTwo
    let total = parseInt(itemOne) + parseInt(itemTwo)
    console.log(total);
```

Comment: Make an array, loop over it, apply `parseInt` to each value in the array…?

Comment: Also, if you don't want to use parseInt, simply you can use unary operator, `+itemOne`

Comment: Note that if by "more efficient" you mean faster than two points: 1. doing it in another way doesn't reduce the total amount of work that needs to be done and probably won't be faster. 2. parsing 20 strings into numbers is not the kind of work that modern computers struggle with, so it will never be the bottleneck (until you try to do it many millions of times per second).

Answer (score 0):

Like this

```js
let itemOne = '111'
let itemTwo = '222'
let itemThree = '333'
let itemFour = '444'

const sum = (...a) => a.reduce((c,e) => c + parseInt(e), 0)

let total = sum(itemOne, itemTwo, itemThree, itemFour)
console.log(total)
```